# Could someone explain why cmd's 'where' does not find this file please?

Tags: node.js, opencv, cmd, path, windows-10

[Boiled down issue:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nkzaE.png)

**Background:**

*I am trying to get opencv4nodejs to install and am running into errors like `opencv2/core.hpp` file not found.*

*Digging into this, knowing full well that I have installed the appropriate files in `C:\tools`, and added all the required paths and refreshed my `cmd.exe` to reflect this, I am still getting hit with errors.*

**Question:**

Could someone please describe why the above commands would lead to `cmd.exe` being unable to find the file I need?

The first `dir %OPENCV_INCLUDE_DIR%opencv2\core.hpp` command clearly shows that it exists within the environment of the console. *Note: This variable has been appended to PATH as `%OPENCV_INCLUDE_DIR%`*

The `where opencv2\core.hpp` cannot find it, much like my other program cannot find it. I am a bit of a cmd noob, so I may be missing something obvious here, but how can this be the case?

Thanks!

Comment: `where /?` from a command prompt. Read the information in the section `pattern`, especially the part that says * The search is also done by **appending the extensions of the PATHEXT variable to the pattern.*** There's no *hpp* in the `PATHEXT`. You can use `set PATHEXT` at a command prompt to see what it contains by default.

Comment: @KenWhite Thanks, that makes more sense. With `where /r %OPENCV_INCLUDE_DIR% core.hpp` I can locate the file. Still, I am left unsure what is causing all these `Cannot open include file: 'opencv2/core.hpp': No such file or directory` errors to remain :( Thanks for the answer though it answered my question :)

Comment: That's not the question you asked here. :-)

Comment: Apologies for unrelated, but anyone landing here pulling their hair out after days of this same issue too, using `opencv4nodejs@5.1.0` as opposed to 5.5.0 was the solution to my issue. Once again though, thank you Ken for answering my main question!

Comment: As far as I'm aware, you cannot provide a directory as part of your `where` pattern, so if the directory `opencv2` isn't in `%PATH%`, `core.hpp` will not be found. I do not believe therefore, unless the new version added the `opencv2` location to `%PATH%` too, that it was a fix for the issue. Depending upon what you'r intention is you could still retrieve its full path another way: `for %i in (opencv2\core.hpp)do @echo "%~$path:i"`.